# What is the fastest way to check 2 fixed size arrays for equality in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, optimization

And why?

Given the following Swift code:

```swift
struct DemoStruct {
    let buf: [UInt8]

    init?(fromArray buf: [UInt8]) {
        guard buf.count == 6 else {
            return nil
        }
        self.buf = buf
    }

    var containsJustZeros: Bool {
        // test code
    }
}

let data = DemoStruct(fromArray: Array(repeating: 0, count: 6))!
if data.containsJustZeros {
    print("zeros")
}
```

For the `test code` part I've implemented and measured the following implementations:

1. `self.buf == Array(repeating: 0, count: 6)`
2. `for dig in self.buf where dig != 0 { return false } return true`
3. `self.buf.elementsEqual(Array(repeating: 0, count: 6))`

Whereas the first code is the fastest (~13 sec/10 000 000 tests) and the last one the slowest (~43 sec/10 000 000 tests). Is there any other implementation possible? I would like to optimise my code for speed and understand Swift much better.

Comment: Is your question about how to check two arrays for equality, or how to check if an array contains only zeros? That are two different questions, and the latter is simply done with `buf.allSatisfy( { $0 == 0 })` .

Comment: Please fix title since it lies abut actual question.

Comment: The question is about equality and how I can optimise my code for fast execution. I've chosen the "zero"-example just for keeping everything as simple as possible. I guess that your answer is another variant of `2. for dig in self.eui where dig != 0 { return false } return true`

Comment: How did you test? Did you remember to use only a Release build? Did you test on a device? How did you measure? Just checking, but I've learned not believe people automatically when they claim they tested something for performance, as they sometimes don't know how.

Comment: I wrote a XCTest whilst I looped over the mentioned property/function 10,000,000 times. The test was executed on my local dev machine (Intel 64bit i5). The test framework gives you a summery at the end about the execution time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: this `Data` struct is a *really* bad idea, that's pretty much certain to lead to confusion. `Foundation` already has a struct called `Data`, and it's totally ubiquitous, because it's the "common currency" type for shuttling around untyped bytes of miscellaneous data.

Furthermore, you don't really get anyhting from using `[UInt8]`. Just use `Foundation.Data`.

As for your main question.

1. The first technique allocates an array, and uses `==` to compare it. There's absolutely no reason to allocate 6 zeros. If `buf` had a billiion elements, would you allocate a billion elements? Wasteful.
2. The second technique is better, because you're not allocating in unnecessary element, just for the sake of comparison. However, it's hand-rolling a feature that already exists in the standard library (`allSatisfy(_:)`, which I'll get into later.)
3. `elementsEqual` is a more generic version of `==`, which can compare one sequence to any other sequence. You chose to compare it to an array of 6 zeros, but that's bad (for the same reason as 0). Instead, you could use `repeatElement(0, count: 6)` to produce an element that doesn't actually need to store `n` copies. It stores just one, and wraps it in a way that conforms to the Collection protocol.

The best approach of all, is to just use `allSatisfy`. It's fast, it doesn't allocate anything unnecessary, and *most importantly* it's descriptive of exactly what you're trying to express:

```
var containsJustZeros: Bool {
    self.buf.allSatisfy { byte in byte == 0 }
}
```

However, I wouldn't implement this in computed property. Those have a conventional expectation of being fast, whereas this is doing a linear scan through the entire buffer. Unless you want to cache the result in a stored boolean property, I would change this to a `func`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have updated my question and sorry for not being precise enough when asking.

Comment: @EvelKnievel so your buffer is just always 6 bytes?

Comment: actually yes, it is a fixed size buffer of 6 bytes and I would like to optimise the comparison with another array of the same size

Comment: How performance hungry are you here? If the answer is "very" (and be careful and make sure you had data to back that up, because it comes at expense of time spent, maintenance overhead, and overall system complexity), then you can just store a tuple of 6 `UInt8`, and use the built-in `==` operator compare it to a `(0,0,0,0,0,0)` literal. If the bytes have some particular meaning in your domain, you can even implement your own comparison function which first compares those bytes which are most likely to differ (to short-circuit earlier and more often).

Comment: This means that `self.buf == [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` would be faster than `self.buf == Array(repeating: 0, count: 6)` because we do not have to allocate the array (because the array is already complied into the binary)?

Comment: In both cases the compiler has the opportunity to identify that these are constant expressions, and can fully elide the heap allocation necessary for them, and potentially even inline the `==` operator definition. You're going to have to play around and look at the compiled assembly. Make sure you remember to enable optimization, or the results will be meaningless. I suggest https://swift.godbolt.org/